# Is it possible to make dateTime.ToString(...) return a different timezone offset?

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

My project is using PDFSharp to normalize creation dates in pdfs. [The issue I'm having is that people in different timezones get different offset values than I do.](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2819)

The problem is PdfSharp allows you to set the creation date but accepts only a `DateTime` which it internally calls this on:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  string delta = this.dateTime.ToString("zzz").Replace(':', '\'');
  return String.Format("D:{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}{1}'", this.dateTime, delta);
}
```

As far as I know `DateTime` has no timezone component, but the fact that `ToString('zzz')` will return the offset gives me hope.

Is it possible to control what `dateTime.ToString('zzz')` returns?

Comment: Override the Override maybe?

Comment: @Jay this is in the PdfSharp source code, not in my own code. I could of course fork it, put a fork up on nuget and use that but that wouldn't be being a very good OSS citizen would it?

Comment: Then just subclass the writer and the instance in your application?

Comment: Wait, that's possible? How do I use my own PdFSharp writer?

Comment: What zone do you want? You can use a UTC `DateTime`, if that would help...

Comment: @JonSkeet Any time zone would do for my purposes, so long as it is constant regardless of where the code is run from.

Comment: I think the problem is that the delta gets mangled in the parsing process regardless according to your question...

Comment: The problem for me is that the offset component for someone running this in New Orleans, USA is different from someone running this in Orleans, France and therefore bytewise file comparisons with ApprovalTests fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, basically `zzz` will *always* use the system default time zone. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zzzSpecifier):

> With `DateTime` values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC, measured in hours and minutes. It does not reflect the value of an instance's `DateTime.Kind` property. For this reason, the "zzz" format specifier is not recommended for use with `DateTime` values.

So you *could* change the system default time zone, but that's pretty extreme. Fundamentally this sounds like PdfSharp is broken by design, and you should file a bug. Even just accepting `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` would be enough to fix this.

Alternatively, as Jay suggested, you could try to create a class which overrides the `ToString` method you've shown us. We can't really tell you how you'd do that without knowing which class it is or what creates the instances of it, but it's definitely a thought.

Comment: Thank Jon, that's what I was afraid of. Dammit. I could look into overriding the class, but this particular class is created internally to PdfSharp (its seems to be a DateTime wrapper) so I'd have to overwrite where THAT is created from and so on and so on because who needs DI when designing an OSS library right?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Are there any alternatives to PdfSharp you can consider? Otherwise, forking the code may be your best bet - certainly if this is a tool which you need to get working soon, but which will not be needed in (say) 6 months...

Comment: Not sure, my needs are pretty simple and I settled on PdfSharp after a cursory nuget search. If I could get some sort of response from the PdfSharp team [I'd even patch this myself](https://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/16846) but they've been pretty unresponsive in the past.

Comment: Ended up cracking the Pdf `MemoryStream` open and churning through it to replace those timezones manually. Gross but interestingly I could not find any other pdf library with a license suitable for Open Source

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Glad it worked out for you in the end :)